# Deserializing legacy XML class types into new class types

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I'm supporting a legacy, internal API that uses two classes that are serialized using *XML*. Both classes are sub-classes of a common base class:

```
namespace My.Namespace {

    [
        Serializable,
        XmlInclude(typeof(SubClassA)),
        XmlInclude(typeof(SubClassB)),
    ]
    public abstract class BaseClass {
        // etc.
    }

    [
        Serializable,
        XmlType(TypeName="My.Namespace.SubClassA"),
    ]
    public sealed class SubClassA: BaseClass {
        // etc.
    }

    [
        Serializable,
        XmlType(TypeName="My.Namespace.SubClassB"),
    ]
    public sealed class SubClassB: BaseClass {
        // etc.
    }
}
```

So far, so good.

However, the two sub-classes have now been refactored into a single new class (the differences between them are minimal), called `SubClass`, which also extends `BaseClass`.

The issue now is that the new class needs to be capable of deserializing legacy *XML* files that define instances of `SubClassA` and `SubClassB`. The problem is that there is no apparent relationship between these types and the new `SubClass` type. (The `SubClassA` and `SubClassB` classes are no longer part of the API and cannot be used to deserialize these instances.)

How do I configure `BaseClass` and `SubClass` so that newly serialized XML files define instances of `SubClass` definitions, while also being able to deserialize legacy *XML* file instances of `SubClassA` and `SubClassB` definitions into instances of `SubClass`? Can I make `SubClassA` and `SubClassB` aliases for `SubClass` when deserializing *XML* files?

(Let's assume that the serialized properties are common to `SubClass`, `SubClassA` and `SubClassB`.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the standard `XmlSerializer` provides the features you need. There may be third-party libraries exists that do, but I don't know of any.

I see the following possible approaches here:

- Manual mapping at the XML-level: use `XDocument` to open the old-version XML and manipulate elements via the XML DOM. Modify the XML so that it becomes a valid XML for the new version of your type. Then use the `XmlSerializer` to deserialize the migrated XML with new-version datatypes.
- Manual mapping at the DTO-level: Store the old datatypes in a separate assembly. Use extern aliases (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern-alias) in case of type name conflicts. Then deserialize the old-version XML into the old-version datatypes. Then manually map the data to the new datatypes. Finally, you can use the objects from the previous step "as is" or serialize them to XML and use such a new-version XML in the future processing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, @serg. The first option you suggest is what I'm trying to avoid: I have a large number of legacy XML files within the company that need to be supported "as-is". As a last resort, that's certainly an option, but it's not an attractive one. :-) I don't think the second option is feasible, as we don't want to require a library dependency upon on an older version of itself. Unless someone can suggest otherwise, it's looking like the only non-hideous option being to retain both `SubClassA` and `SubClassB` as sub-classes of `SubClass`. :-(